# How to redirect 40,000 urls with the same url structure efficiently?

Tags: redirect

The 40,000 urls have the same structure between them.

How can we redirect 40,000 urls in bulk instead of inputting each url 1 by 1?

Here's a sample format of the url structure:

www.website.com/School-A-Cost to www.website.com/School-A/Cost

www.website.com/School-B-Cost to www.website.com/School-B/Cost

Answer (score 2):

That can be solved without WordPress per .htaccess (or whatever config file your webserver is using).

Example for .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent /School-(.*)-Cost /School-$1/Cost
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in WP but there isn't much specific to WordPress here besides [wp_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect).

This chunk of code could go in a plugin to speed up the check or just dropped into your functions.php. Essentially you want to run this as soon as possible before WP has to think too hard.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_20160508_check_redirects' ) ) {
    function wpse_20160508_check_redirects() {

        $request  = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
        $redirect = '';

        /**
         *      http://example.com/School-A-Cost/ -> http://example.com/School-A/Cost/
         */

        if ( preg_match( "/(School-(.*))-(Cost)(\/.*)?/", $request, $matches ) && count( $matches ) >= 3 ) {

            $path = $matches[ 1 ] . '/' . $matches[ 3 ];

            if ( isset( $matches[ 4 ] ) ) {
                $path .= $matches[ 4 ];
            }

            $redirect = site_url( $path );
        }

        if ( ! empty ( $redirect ) ) {
            wp_redirect( $redirect, 301 );
            exit();
        }
    }
}

// Run as soon as possible
wpse_20160508_check_redirects();
```

As you can see it'll take a URL like `/School-A-Cost/this-is-extra?foo=bar` and checks for matches to the regular expression.

```
Array
(
    [0] => School-A-Cost/this-is-extra?foo=bar
    [1] => School-A
    [2] => A
    [3] => Cost
    [4] => /this-is-extra?foo=bar
)
```

From there you can put those parts together to form a new location `/School-A/Cost/this-is-extra?foo=bar` which you'll redirect to.